# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display the map of the US using d3. I currently have this code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // width and height of the svg
            var width = 960,
                height = 600;  
            //projection of the US map
            var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();
            //path of the US map projection
            var path = d3.geo.projection(projection);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("path").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

            //d3.select("body").append("p").text("New paragraph123");
    </script>
</body>
```

I get an error on the browser that says 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" and points to "d3.v3.min.js:2." Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably this line: `var path = d3.geo.projection(projection);` I think you mean `var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);`.

Comment: @BenLyall awesome! That made the error go away. The map still doesn't show up though. Would you know why?

Comment: There is no map, that's why there's nothing showing up.  I'd suggest you take a look at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Comment: @BenLyall isn't the d3.geo.albersUsa() the map?

Comment: No, that just sets up a projection that will convert latitude/longitude values into x,y co-ordinates that you can draw on an SVG or canvas.  You need to provide a shapefile in GeoJSON or TopoJSON format and pass that through a projected path generator.  The link I posted earlier goes through what you need to do, from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var width = 960,
height = 470;
var projection = d3.geo.naturalEarth(),
graticule = d3.geo.graticule();
var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
svg.append("path").datum(graticule).attr("class", "graticule").attr("d", path);
svg.append("path").datum(graticule.outline).attr("class", "graticule outline").attr("d", path);
d3.json("world.json", function(world) {
var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features,
neighbors = topojson.neighbors(world.objects.countries.geometries);
svg.selectAll(".country").data(countries).enter().insert("path", ".graticule").attr("class", "country").attr("d", path)
});
```

```css
.country {
fill: #ccc;
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: .5px;
stroke-linejoin: round;
}
.graticule {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
stroke-opacity: .3;
stroke-width: .5px;
}
.graticule.outline {
stroke: #333;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart" style="margin-left:40px;"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Get world.json from here http://blog.csaladen.es/f1%20circuits/world.json

Comment: Ben Lyall's comment up top fixed it for me. Thank you though!